# Can not resolve junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2 and junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2 with Gradle 6.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, junit, junit5

I have an Android project with 2 Android modules and one pure Java module.
After updating the android build tools to com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0 and the gradle wrapper to gradle-6.1.1-all the pure Java module can not resolve junit anymore.
I get the following error while syncing with the gradle files:

```
Failed to resolve: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2 
Failed to resolve: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2
```

If I try to run the tests directly I get the following output:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':domain:testCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2.
     Required by:
         project :domain
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2:
          - javadocElements
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
                  - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '7' but no value provided.
                  - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'classes' but no value provided.
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'jvm' but no value provided.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
                  - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '7' but no value provided.
                  - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'classes' but no value provided.
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'jvm' but no value provided.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

How can I tell Gradle where it should look for the correct junit dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I have found for a similar issue (mine was with org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api) is to update the source compatibility of the tests to 1.8.

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
    targetCompatibility = "1.7"
}
compileTestJava {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"
}
```

This way the production source is still compatible with 1.7 to allow the Android build.